# Trouble with Graphics 2d translation and rotation

Tags: java, rotation, translation, graphics2d, affinetransform

I am making a 2d top down game and I want the player to be able to move freely and rotate to "face" the mouse. This all works perfectly but once the player is moved, and the camera translates the facing the mouse effect doesn't work anymore.

Camera:

```
x = (player.getX()+(player.getWidth()/2)) - game.getWidth()/2;
y = (player.getY()+(player.getHeight()/2)) - game.getHeight()/2;

g2d.translate(-camX, -camY);
//render everything(including player)
g2d.translate(camX, camY);
```

Rotating mouse(in the players draw method):

```
g2d.rotate(Math.atan2(playerCenterY - mouseY, playerCenterX - mouseX) - Math.PI / 2 , playerCenterX , playerCenterY );
//draw player
g2d.rotate(-Math.atan2(playerCenterY - mouseY, playerCenterX - mouseX) - Math.PI / 2 , playerCenterX , playerCenterY );
```

here are some images, where the highlighted arrow is where the mouse is. (the side of the cube should be facing the mosue, not the corner)

this is what it should look like (before the camera moves):

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQI6G.png]

this is what it looks like when id doesn't work any more (after the camera has translated:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9BKb.png]

Comment: This is the fourth time you've posted this question in roughly 24 hours. While I appreciate that your issue is very, very important to you, you also need to understand, as a international community, it might take several days before every one logs in, so it might take some time before some with the knowledge you need comes online. It is generally discouraged to keep reposting like this

Comment: Just wanted to add, I find your overall question interesting and would love to know what other ideas people have about solving it

Comment: sorry, wont happen agian